# ASCII FBX files are not supported

Tags: import, .fbx, encoding

When attempting to import an FBX file that is ASCII encoded, it produces an error "ASCII FBX files are not supported" requiring the files to be converted to hex before import.

The only solution I can find for this is to either get 3DS Max which has an FBX converter, or re-save the file in Visual Studio (which saves them in hex).

I don't have 3DS Max, I do have Visual Studio - but, I need to convert hundreds of FBX files which would take several hours to manually re-save them all through Visual Studio.

Is there any batch method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free [Autodesk Fbx Converter](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=22694909) to batch convert multiple fbx files to various formats. It comes with a cli command which can be used to automate the conversion. I tried but couldn't find any FOSS alternatives to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which program you used to export your original 'ASCII FBX' files, but I was having the same problem.

I've bought a .unity3d file from Heroforge thats compatible with tabletop simulator. I used a program called asset ripper from Github to break up the file to get at the mesh, and export it as an FBX file.

Blender wont support the 'ASCII FBX' file, but when I exported the file as FBX the second time, I found a drop down option to change 'ASCII' to 'binary'.

Now the file opens in Blender! Job done.